# How do I make a div shift above or below another div based on the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my situation:

I have a bunch of rows. In each row is a button that when clicked displays a set of options. Depending on where the row is in the page, the settings need to open above or below the button. If the button is at the top of the page, the settings would display beneath the button. If the button is at the bottom of the page, it should open above.

If the user picks something at the bottom of the page, but then scrolls so it's towards the top, I need the settings to shift under the button as opposed to on top. What's the best way to do this? I'm not actually sure of ANY way to do this, so any advice would  be appreciated.

Comment: That's quite a complex question, can you show some HTML to illustrate the example, or set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Should be straight forward, use two classes for each position of the options, get the scrollTop position and compare against the elements offset to see if it's at the top or bottom of the screen, and swap classes accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery UI's [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) it will do the collision detection for you and is very easy to customise if requirements change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/573zJ/

Test the position of the element relative to the viewport midpoint, and move it to the first or last position relative to its container, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element-set">
        <div class="normal">content</div>
        <div class="flipper">flipper</div>
    </div>

    ... random number of .element-set

    <div class="element-set">
        <div class="normal">content</div>
        <div class="flipper">flipper</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    flippers();
});

function flippers() {
    var midpoint = $(window).height() / 2;
    $('.flipper').each( function () {

        var $flipper = $(this);
        var $parent = $flipper.parent();
        var top = $parent.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if ( top > midpoint ) {
            $flipper.prependTo( $parent );
        } else {
            $flipper.appendTo( $parent );
        }
    });
}
```